# How do you fix a Windows 7 or newer machine generating an "INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE" stop code caused by changing the storage device?

Tags: windows, boot

A very reliable way to cause `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` stop codes is to do one of the following:

- In a virtual machine, install Windows, then later change the hardware device that the boot drive is connected to (for instance, changing its storage adapter type from SATA to IDE while still pointing at the same disk image file)
- On a physical machine, change the hard drive type in the BIOS (SATA/AHCI/RAID)

This makes sense - Windows expects its boot drive at a certain ID on a certain hardware device.

**This is often a misconfiguration, but please pretend for the sake of this question that the hardware change was fully intended**. Perhaps we installed on an IDE drive, but then copied that install to a SATA drive and wish to boot from it, or we changed the hardware type in a VM to work around some bug or performance problem.

What is the proper method to reconfigure Windows to recognize the new hardware and boot from it normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to run
[Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
from a Windows installation media, and a recovery drive.

In some hard cases, such as changing the drive type to/from AHCI,
may require
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If the computer is UEFI and still remembers the old disk with its
Windows installation, you may need to
[Delete Old Boot Menu Options](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/delete-boot-menu-options-windows/)
using MSConfig, BCDedit or other tools.